# How do I call a constructor from a class when the constructor class is extended?

Tags: constructor

So I'm having trouble with a constructor. I'm calling a constructor from my Tile class into my Square class and the constructor supposedly has no parameters.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.imageio.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Square extends Tile
    {
        static BufferedImage square = null;

        public void Square()
        {
            try
            {
               square = ImageIO.read(new File("BlueSquare.png"));
            }
            catch (IOException e){}
        }

        public Square(int dVal, boolean walk, BufferedImage image)
        {
            super(1, true, square);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Tile class.

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.awt.image.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import javax.imageio.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    public class Tile
    {
        static int dataVal;
        static boolean walkable;
        static BufferedImage img;

        public void Tile (int dVal, boolean walk, BufferedImage image)
        {
            dataVal = dVal;
            walkable = walk;
            img = image;
        }

        public static int getValue()
        {
            return dataVal;
        }

        public static boolean getWalk()
        {
            return walkable;
        }

        public static BufferedImage getImage()
        {
            return img;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`public void Square()` is *not* a constructor; it's just a method with a terrible naming convention.

`public Square()` *is* a constructor with three arguments.  It calls the `Tile` constructor, which also has three arguments.

Remove the `void`:

```
public void Tile (int dVal, boolean walk, BufferedImage image)
```

should be:

```
public Tile (int dVal, boolean walk, BufferedImage image)
```

Your method names are heinous.  No wonder you're confused.  Change those method names to something that starts with a lower case letter and doesn't use the class name (e.g. "createSquareImage").

Read the Sun Java coding conventions.  You need to know them.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed the naming and the pictures are fine now.